# Call two async functions in a row within React app

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have two `async` functions which reach out to API endpoints (Serverless Framework) - one gets and returns a token, the other gets and returns data using the token.

I'm testing these by using simple buttons, where `onClick` calls the functions to pull the token and the data, respectively. Click one button to get the token, which is saved to state. Then, once I see the token has been received, I click the other button to get the data. This works without any issues at all.

The problem is when I try calling them sequentially from the React app. I need to call these back-to-back when the user submits a request. I can't seem to make the code wait for the token to arrive before trying to pull the data.

The functions being called in the `onClick` method of the button:

```
const tokenBtnOnClick = () =>
{
  const response = getToken().then(x => {
    setToken(x.data.response.token)
  })
}

const dataBtnOnClick = () =>
{
  const response = getData(token, param1, param2, param3).then(x => {
    setData(x.data.response)
  })
}
```

`Async` functions:

```
export async function getToken()
{
    const apiUrl = `${BASE_URL}/handler/getToken`
    const axios = require('axios').default

    let response
    try
    {
        response = await axios.get(apiUrl)
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        console.log(e)
    }

    if (response)
    {
        return response
    }
    else
    {
        return ''
    }
}

export async function getData(token, param1, param2, param3)
{
    const apiUrl = `${BASE_URL}/handler/getData?token=${token}&param1=${param1}&param2=${param2}&param3=${param3}`
    const axios = require('axios').default

    let response
    try
    {
        response = await axios.post(apiUrl)
    }
    catch (e)
    {
        console.log(e)
    }

    if (response)
    {
        return response
    }
    else
    {
        return ''
    }
}
```

I've tried calling this `getBoth()` function in a single button's `onClick`:

```
async function getBoth()
{
  const tokenResponse = await tokenBtnOnClick().then(x => setToken(x.data.response.token))
  const dataResponse = await dataBtnOnClick().then(x => setData(x.data.response))
}
```

But even though it's an `async` function that uses `await` on both lines, I always get the same `TypeError` because `dataBtnOnClick` is called immediately, without actually waiting for the token to come in. When I run this code, `tokenBtnOnClick` is called, the app crashes due to a `TypeError`, and then the token comes in and is logged and saved to state.

I've also tried this: (where `getData` is exactly as above, but now accepts `token` as a paramter rather than using the state variable)

```
async function getBoth()
{
  const response = await getToken().then(x => getData(x.data.response.token))
}
```

> index.js?bee7:59 Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Cannot read
> properties of undefined (reading 'then')

How do I get this to actually wait for the token to come in before trying to pull the data?

Comment: It's most likely waiting like you expect, but `token` is now stale because there has been  no re-render between the two calls. You'll need to pass in the token directly from the first ajax call into the second function instead of trying to use the state variable.

Comment: @BrianThompson I've tried that also. I'll add it to the post

Comment: So the error is your problem.. not the async code... Please be sure that all relevant details are included in your question. `tokenBtnOnClick` doesn't appear to return a promise, so you can't chain `.then` on it

Comment: Also don't mix await and `.then` syntax. They do similar things and it just makes the code harder to follow

Comment: What is happening is that you are overthinking it, you can simplify your code and then obtain your result, eg: you are using promises and async functions together

Answer (score 0):

You are calling `setToken` and expection `token` to be updated immediately, but `setToken` will be asynchronously applied.

Can you `useEffect` to solve your problem?

```
useEffect(() => {
  getData(token, param1, param2, param3).then(x => {
    setData(x.data.response)
  })
}, [token])
```

Comment: I'm new to this but I was under the impression that `await` in an `async` function will pause the code until a response is received. Thanks for suggesting `useEffect` - reading that it is the best approach to `async` functions in React. But how can I use a `useEffect` call to get the token and data at the same time?

Comment: Get the token the way you are already, and `setToken`, then the effect will run to get data.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    const tokenBtnOnClick = () =>{
       setToken(getToken())
    }

    const dataBtnOnClick = () =>{
       setData(getData(token, param1, param2, param3))
    }
```

and

```
const axios = require('axios').default

export async function getToken()
 let apiUrl = `${BASE_URL}/handler/getToken`
{    
    let response = await axios.get(apiUrl)  


        return response.data.token;
        //i don't know exactly what the api returns so it may be diferent

}

export async function getData(token, param1, param2, param3)
{
    let apiUrl = `${BASE_URL}/handler/getData? token=${token}&param1=${param1}&param2=${param2}&param3=${param3}`


    let response = await axios.post(apiUrl)
    return response.data.response;


}
```

and in your getBoth() just call them because the functions are asynchronous the code will only move forward after them are finished

```
 getBoth(){
     setToken(getToken())
     setData(getData(token, param1, param2, param3))
 }
```